# Hardcode higher order string arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to find a method for creating high order arrays (specifically 3D, but higher too if possible) in VBA in as few characters as possible.

My current approach is simply to use the Evaluate() function (shorthand `[]`) in VBA. This effectively acts like a cell in a spreadsheet, and evaluates the string within according to Excel formula conventions.

To hardcode a reference to an array in Excel, you use the following convention; 1D uses comma separator:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

and 2D uses the semicolon separator:

```
{1, 2; 3, 4}
```

Meaning to create a 2D array in VBA I just type

```
myarray = [{1, 2; 3, 4}]
```

As you can see, this is much more succinct than the equivalent

```
myarray = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))
```

I am wondering what's the lowest character count approach for a 3D (or higher) order array?

Is there a way of creating a 3D array reference in a cell in Excel, then using `[]` to get it into VBA? Or a better VBA only approach

I'm looking for whatever method uses the fewest characters!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CallumDA Well I lied a little, I'm actually trying to create a 3D array in *VBA* in as few characters as possible. So far I've been using `[{array}]`, where `{array}` is an array reference in the Excel style. This works for 1 and 2D arrays using the array format as stated in my question, so I'm wondering if there's a similar thing for 3D arrays in Excel, or if not, then what's the shortest Excel formula that can get me one.

Comment: That already sounds more interesting than the question you posted. Why don't you post your full code so that we can think about it in the right context?

Comment: @CallumDA Ok, I'll edit accordingly

Comment: @CallumDA I have changed the problem scope. Hopefully from reading it you can see why I haven't actually got a specific bit of code to share; I'm after a general approach rather than a fix of some existing code (although you can see the `array()` method which could easily be extended to 3D as my current fallback approach)

Comment: Nice question now. I'll have a good think about it and I'm keen to see what people come up with!